# Hypertable time-based partitions with denormalized date column

Tags: timescaledb

typical data warehouse db schemata often follow a [star schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema#Example) with denormalized date and time columns. That means that the fact table (the one that should be a hypertable when using timescaledb) has no column containing a timestamp but instead has foreign keys to the data and time tables.

Is there a way to make timescaledb aware of this and partition the fact table correctly despite this? Or is a timestamp-column a hard requirement for a hypertable?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timescale requires to provide a time column for partitioning. It is not required to be a timestamp, but can be, for example, an integer value. See [the doc](https://docs.timescale.com/v1.3/api#create_hypertable-units)

If `int` is used instead of time, it is important that it increases in the same way as the time. Note that in such case it is necessary to provide `chunk_time_interval`.

It is also possible to provide `time_partitioning_func`, which will convert references into time compatible values.

See description of [`create_hypertable`](https://docs.timescale.com/v1.3/api#create_hypertable)

Comment: While you can proceed along these lines, I might recommend that you use functions to extract the information contained in that example of a date field, they are built in and will likely be more efficient. The other thing is to use the date as the id for that table, in which case you can still have a separate table if you really care to, but I think in most cases it is likely to be an anti-pattern.